# How to Lock (not sleep) my Mac using NSAppleScript or any other command that can be executed from a Mac app

Tags: macos, swift2, nsapplescript

In my Mac app i am trying to lock my Mac based on some actions in my app. Until now i have only got a way to put it to sleep but not lock.
Currently i am doing this :

```
let appleScript = NSAppleScript(source: "tell application \"Finder\" to sleep")
        appleScript?.executeAndReturnError(nil)
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
tell application "Finder" to sleep
```

Use the following:

```
do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend"
```

You will need to escape the " characters with \ as you have already with the Finder command.

Comment: But this is a bash command i am trying to achieve the same using AppleScript.

Comment: Applescript can run this shell script. There is no direct command that can do what you ask, although some have had luck with using the button found in the Keychain application using the following `tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer" to click (first menu item of menu 1 of ((click (first menu bar item whose description is "Keychain menu extra")) of menu bar 1) whose title is "Lock Screen")`. See more options here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80058/lock-screen-command-one-liner